# "Пофиг" и "по фигу"

Tags: значение-слов, слитно-раздельно, смысл, жаргон

Нашёл [тут](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=252106&v=full) рекомендации по слитному/раздельному написанию "фиговых" слов, вот только не могу понять разницы между указанными словами. А если окажется, что это одно и то же, тогда совсем странно, что от добавления окончания У слово начинает писаться раздельно.

Comment: А в БТС рекомендуется слитное.

Comment: Разница-то есть в смысле?

Comment: Нет (из-за того что, по сути, то же слово), только в плавности звучания.

Comment: Неграмотная грамота. Пофиг - только так по-русски (в более классическом варианте тоже, от которого оно и образовано), в противном случае вы получите этот самый фиг, а не переносное значение. Кстати, этим мат и отличается от обсценной лексики, он не апеллирует к физическому, употребление мата в физическом плане - это грубость и ругань, а в переносном - это образный язык. Физиологизация фигов характерна именно для англоязычной брани, но при переводе происходит проникновение бранной культуры и возникают формы вроде на фиг(но ударение именно не на него).

Comment: Пофиг, нафиг, нафига и тд, - слитно и наречия, по-русски. Есть неплохая статья про мат на Лурке. Обсценная лексика - для ругани, мат - это не ругань, а образный язык и профессиональный диалект. Если взять англоязычную брань, то фразы вроде мазафакер дословно значат "вступивший в секс связь с собственной матерью", а переводят это как "..твою мать", смысл которого "я тебе в отцы гожусь, слушай меня". Мат - это не способ оскорбить собеседника, а попытка его образумить, в то время как цель обсценной лексики унижение достоинства. Долбан - человек который сделал хрень, ничего более, - исправится.

Answer (score 1):

Интересно обосновать то или иное написание.

```
по фиг
```

Винительный падеж после предлога по. Раздельный вариант предполагает измерение и неявный глагол: **Ты мне по горло уже (осточертела).** Слитный вариант не предполагает глагола, а является предикативом: **Ты мне никак.**

Итак, лингвистический тест на раздельное написание мы придумали и обосновали, осталось подставить туда слово **по фиг** и посмотреть, пройдет ли оно тест:

```
Ты мне по фиг осточертела // некорректно
```

Тест на раздельное написание не пройден. Значит написание слитно и никак иначе.

```
пофигу
```

Здесь раздельный вариант возможен. Как в стандартных наречно-предложных выражениях.  [Например, мне до лампочки](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cj0KHNC80L3QtSDQtNC%2BINC70LDQvNC%2F0L7Rh9C60LgqFgoICAAQChgyIAogACju7%2BOA%2BZQ4QAUyAggBOgEBMAE%3D)
Однако со временем наречно-предложные выражения превращаются в наречия, приобретая слитное написание. Поэтому в БТС рекомендуют слитно, а где-то раздельно.

Comment: Если раздельно, то ударение не на предлоге.

Comment: Да, тест на ударение тоже отличная идея.

Comment: @oleedd: на предлоге всё равно, посмотри на красную букву в моей ссылке.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Но это нелогично.